# In forEach loop, only last value is shown

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I am using the MET API to show the information of each art piece in a specific department. To do this I am trying to loop through an array, `first10`, using `forEach`. When I look in the console.log, I can see each `objs` in `first10`, but once it gets to `object.onload`, I only get the "card" of the last `objs` in the array.

This is the HTML:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
        </head>
    
        <body id="home">
            <main id="results-container"></main>
            <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
let resultsBody = document.getElementById('results-container');

      objects.open('GET', `https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects?departmentIds=6`, true);
      objects.onload = function() {
        let data2 = JSON.parse(this.response);
        if (objects.status >= 200 && objects.status < 400) {
          let first10 = data2.objectIDs.slice(0, 4);
          intr = 0;
          first10.forEach(objs => {
            object.open('GET', `https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/${objs}`, true);
            object.onload = function() {
              let data3 = JSON.parse(this.response);
              if (object.status >= 200 && object.status < 400) {
                  const card = document.createElement('div');
                  card.setAttribute('class', 'card');
                  const images = document.createElement('div');
                  images.innerHTML = `<img src="${data3['primaryImageSmall']}">`;

                  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
                  h1.style.color = "black";
                  h1.textContent = data3['title'];

                  const p = document.createElement('p');
                  p.style.color = "black";
                  p.textContent = data3['artistDisplayName'];

                  resultsBody.appendChild(card);
                  card.appendChild(images);
                  card.appendChild(h1);
                  card.appendChild(p);
                // }
              }
            }
            object.send();
          });
        }
      }
      objects.send();
```

I have been trying to figure out how to make a "card" with the information of each `objs`.
I have been looking at other questions that relate to mine, but I did not really understand how it applies to my problem since I am still starting in JavaScript.

Comment: Note that statuses in the 300s may cause you issues. I'd make sure you understand what status is used by the MET in their APIs to signal "success with data" (normally 200) and use that specifically to prevent unforeseen errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should declare `new XMLHttpRequest();`
in each every forEach iteration:

```
first10.forEach(objs => {
 /*HERE*/ let object  = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 object.open('GET', `https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects/${objs}`, true);
```

otherwise you're re-assigning the new calls for the same object so you get the last one only.

Comment: OMG thank you so much. You don't know how long I have been struggling with this. Bless your heart and your brain.